# Can't merge PDFs with PyPDF2 - ValueError

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I try to merge PDFs I have downloaded from Google Drive and I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'F-1.4'
```

This does not happen when I merge PDFs that I generated with Keynote.

The full error reads like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weekly_meeting.py", line 36, in <module>
    file_path = sort_pdf(path)
  File "weekly_meeting.py", line 15, in sort_pdf
    pdf_merger.append(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/merger.py", line 151, in merge
    outline = pdfr.getOutlines()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1346, in getOutlines
    lines = catalog["/Outlines"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 516, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/generic.py", line 178, in getObject
    return self.pdf.getObject(self).getObject()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1599, in getObject
    idnum, generation = self.readObjectHeader(self.stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1667, in readObjectHeader
    return int(idnum), int(generation)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'F-1.4'
```

I tried

- opening the PDF Files - they are normal working PDF
- exporting them with Preview, again as PDF - they still produce the error
- other PDFs - they seem to work fine

This is my code, the problems seems to be the pdf_merger.append(file):

```
def sort_pdf(path):
    pdf_merger = PdfFileMerger()
    if (os.path.isdir(path)):
        head, file_name = os.path.split(path)
        os.chdir(path)
        chronology = ["OVERVIEW", "CUSTOMER", "PROJECT", "PERSONAL"]
        for prefix in chronology:
            for file in glob.glob(prefix + "*.pdf"):
                pdf_merger.append(file)
        file_path = path + "/" + file_name + ".pdf"
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as result:
            pdf_merger.write(result)
        return file_path
```

I expected the output to be a sorted and combined PDF, which I already have achieved with other documents.

Comment: Look like your input PDF is broken. This `b'F-1.4'` should read `b'%PDF-1.4'`

Comment: I guess that is something I could solve programmatically, right? Check the header and repair it before I try to sort the PDF?
Any idea how I could change the file header?

Comment: *"could solve programmatically, right? "*: **No**, verify if you can open the PDF with a PDF-Reader. Open with a editor, e.g. leafpad, an verify if the first chars are equal to `'%PDF-1.4'`.

Comment: Relevant: [PyPDF2/issues/183](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/183)

Comment: I solved it by just writing the header:
pdf_reader._header = b_("%PDF-1.4")

Answer (score 1):

> Look like your input PDF is broken. This b'F-1.4' should read b'%PDF-1.4' – stovfl

Using the PdfFileReader and PdfFileWriter instead of the PdfFilerMerge with the following code solved the problem for me:

```
for file in glob.glob(prefix + "*.pdf"):
                pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file)
                pdf_reader._header = b_("%PDF-1.4")
                for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
                    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))
```

Just overwriting the header beasically.

Comment: You make `PdfFileReader` happy, but the `PDF` is still broken.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. It is based on [this](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/183#issuecomment-608618569), I just completed the code with import statement and fixed indentation issues.

```
import PyPDF2

pdfs = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf']

pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

# loop through all PDFs
for filename in pdfs:
    # rb for read binary
    pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    # Opening each page of the PDF
    for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
        pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

# save PDF to file, wb for write binary
pdfOutput = open('output.pdf', 'wb')
# Outputting the PDF
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
# Closing the PDF writer
pdfOutput.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per original question comments.

You should not attempt merging broken PDF files until after repairs have been validated.

There is no one method to know a PDF is too bad for merging with another, as often Acrobat may show contents, before asking to save fixes when closing the PDF. The OP apparently had faults in the Header of the file, and simply correct the header, will often cascade errors throughout **all following objects, thus whole file.**

The odd message that Adobe Acrobat MAY throw when opening a file will usually be when a file is too badly corrupted to open and fix.
[image]
Traditionally this is when the tail of the file is incorrect and another PDF reader may test and offer a fix **before showing it**.

Here is a good reader/editor error message
[image]

So direct answer to question is, **investigate what the exact error is** and fix bad PDF correctly before merging. Reprinting /rebuilding may simply hide another downstream problem.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of PyPDF2, we can use pypdf and use this below code to get rid of this issue.

```
# pip install pypdf
import os
import pypdf

pdfs = ['sample-1.pdf', 'sample-2.pdf']

pdfmerger = pypdf.PdfWriter()
new_pdf = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'merged_file.pdf')

for pdf in pdfs:
  pdfmerger.append(pdf)

pdfmerger.write(new_pdf)
pdfmerger.close()
```

Links : https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/merging-pdfs.html